# Preventing any message loss during failover in Amazon MQ (ActiveMQ) with high throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I am testing failover in Amazon MQ (ActiveMQ) for active/standby broker configuration and experiencing message loss. I am sending messages in persistent mode and using `setUseAsyncSend(true)` to achieve high throughput without waiting for acknowledgements during send. My understanding is that during failover, a few messages that have not been persisted to disk (EFS) and are still in memory are lost. Is there any way to prevent those message loss in Amazon MQ without affecting throughput? Please note that I am trying to test this scenario while performing a performance test to ensure high throughput and high reliability. Since there is a high volume of incoming data, there is a chance that some messages in the queue are not yet persisted.

Additional context: I am conducting these tests to evaluate the performance of Amazon MQ in terms of high throughput and high reliability. Due to the high volume of incoming data, there is a possibility that some messages in the queue have not yet been persisted.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if you want to ensure that a message makes it to the broker and is persisted (i.e. will survive a broker failure) then you need to send it *synchronously* (i.e. the client needs to send the message and then wait for a response from the broker that everything is OK).

Of course, sending the message synchronously will have a significant negative impact on performance vs sending the messages *asynchronously* which is ostensibly why you're using `setUseAsyncSend(true)`. The problem here is that the client has no way to know if the message actually made it to the broker successfully since it doesn't wait for any kind of response. So while this improves throughput, it significantly reduces reliability.

The [CompletionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/CompletionListener.html) was introduced in JMS 2 to allow messages to be sent **both** asynchronously and reliably via a callback. Unfortunately, ActiveMQ "Classic" doesn't support this functionality (although [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) does). To be clear, `CompletionListener` support in ActiveMQ "Classic" is planned and can be tracked [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8324).

I believe your best (if not your only) option to improve throughput while maintaining reliability is by batching your sends up into transactions. Then you can send asynchronously and commit every so often (e.g. 250 messages) to be sure all those messages were successfully persisted. If the transaction fails then you can resend that batch.

Comment: ActiveMQ v5.18.1 has most of JMS 2 features completed. CompletionListener support is planned and can be tracked by this JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8324